# Java client server chat pads strings with squares when converting to byte[]

Tags: java, string, arrays

I'm building a chat client and server as part of a class project and running into one problem I can't seem to fix.  Text has to be passed in the form of fixed size `byte[]` (either 32 or 64 bytes) depending on the particular case.

When I change the strings to `byte[]` with the `.getBytes()` method it pads out the length of the string with empty squares. This is fine during transit and receipt but at some point I need to change the string to it's original format (currently done with `new String(byte[])` and delete the empty squares.

I can't seem to find a good way to do this. Any suggestions?

Relevant code bits client side:

```
byte[] bigDataByte = new byte[64];
sendData[2] = (bigDataByte = message.getBytes())
for (int i = 0; i < sendData.length; i++){
    if (sendData[i] != null){
        DatagramPacket sendPacket = new DatagramPacket(sendData[i], sendData[i].length, IPAddress, clientPort);
        clientSocket.send(sendPacket);
    }
}
```

Relevant code bits server side:

```
 String name = new String(getBytes(32));

 private static byte[] getBytes(int size) throws IOException {
    byte[] dataByte = new byte[size];
    DatagramPacket dataPacket = new DatagramPacket(dataByte, dataByte.length);
    servSocket.receive(dataPacket);
    return dataPacket.getData();
 }
```

Comment: Can you post only the relevant part of your code?

Comment: I wonder if .trim() would work, It's so simple I hadn't thought of it.  It depends on whether the blank square chars are considered white space.

Comment: Yes, it did work.  Sorry, I should have thought of that earlier, just didn't think the squares would be "blank space."

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, but the issue might be that you are not specifying the charset.

Try using the

- constructor: [`String(byte[] bytes, String charsetName)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#String%28byte%5b%5d,%20java.lang.String%29)
- and the method: [`getBytes(String charsetName)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#getBytes%28java.lang.String%29).

e.g.

```
byte[] bytes = str.getBytes("UTF-8");
```

and

```
String str = new String(bytes, "UTF-8");
```

The default ones use the platform's default charset, which could lead to a mismatch.